# Получаю пустые сообщения через VK LongPoll API

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Начал работу с VK LongPoll API через их SDK для Java. Когда я сделал "слушатель" сообщений и начал писать в сообщество, чьи сообщения я и контроллирую, увидел, что ВК посылает пустые сообщения. Вывод выглядит так: "{}", хотя должен выводить строковое представление объекта сообщения. Все необходимые разрешения получены, токен рабочий. Код без токена и id группы представлен ниже:

```
 public class Main {
        private static final String TOKEN = "проверенный_рабочий_токен";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TransportClient transportClient = HttpTransportClient.getInstance();
            VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);

            Random random = new Random();

            GroupActor actor = new GroupActor(id_группы, TOKEN);


            MessagesHandler messagesHandler = new MessagesHandler(vk, actor);
            try {
                messagesHandler.run();
            } catch (ClientException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

  class MessagesHandler extends CallbackApiLongPoll{
        @Override
        public void messageNew(Integer groupId, Message message) {
            super.messageNew(groupId, message);
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        public MessagesHandler(VkApiClient client, GroupActor actor) {
            super(client, actor);
        }
    }
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Поменяйте местами super.messageNew и ваш System.out.println

Comment: Поменял местами и протестировал. Не помогло :(